# How to combine border-color and border-width property given that border-top and border-bottom should equal zero?

Tags: css

My college homework got returned with mentor's remark:

```
{
border: 1px solid red;
border-width: 0 1px;
}
```

should be combined in one border property,

which for the life of me, I can't figure out.
The whole thing is about giving a div only left and right borders.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, this is exactly what I thought: its impossible to follow the mentor's remark as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

{    border-left: 1px solid red;
        border-right: 1px solid red;}

Comment: Thank you very much, we lost the "red" here..

Comment: you can just add red after solid for both rules, but this is still 2 rules - arguably easier to read but not really better than what OP had.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple box-shadow values in one rule with a comma. Technically possible but I would not be pleased with your mentor if this is the anticipated answer...

```css
span {
box-shadow: -1px 0 0 0 red, 1px 0 0 0 red;
}
```

```html
<span>
OMG
</span>
```